# Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't throw unhandled exception

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I Have the following code, the exception thrown by **methodThatThrowsException** get silent, how can I throw the exception ?

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(MethodThatThrowsException)
                        .ContinueWith(t => { throw t.Exception; }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, scheduler)
                        .ContinueWith(w => Vm.StatusMessage.StopProgressBar(), token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, scheduler);
```

Comment: Please see Exception Handling in TPL at; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why the downvotes, it's been 2 hours that i'm looking for a solution, couln't find the answer on Stack Overflow or else where?  Thanks to give the reason for downvotes so I can edit my question accordingly..

Comment: Seems like if you google your question with your exact title you will get this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982294/why-doesnt-my-process-terminate-when-task-has-unhandled-exception and it has same reference link that I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the exception of the task by accessing the task.Exception property.

```
   Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(MethodThatThrowsException)
                    .ContinueWith(t => { throw t.Exception; }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, scheduler)
                    .ContinueWith(w => Vm.StatusMessage.StopProgressBar(), token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, scheduler);

   System.Exception yourException = task.Exception;
```